# Scheduling a task at a fixed time of the day with Akka

Tags: scala, scheduled-tasks, akka

I am a beginner with Akka. I need to schedule a task each day at a fixed time of the day, say 8AM. What I know how to do is scheduling a task periodically, for instance

```
import akka.util.duration._

scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 10 minutes) {
  doSomething()
}
```

> What is the simplest way to schedule tasks at fixed times of the day in Akka?

### A small parenthesis

It is easy to do what I want just using this feature. A toy implementation would look like

```
scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 24 hours) {
  val now = computeTimeOfDay()
  val delay = desiredTime - now

  scheduler.scheduleOnce(delay) {
    doSomething()
  }
}
```

It is not difficult, but I introduced a little race condition. In fact, consider what happens if I launch this just before 8AM. The external closure will start, but by the time I compute `delay` we may be after 8AM. This means that the internal closure - which should execute right away - will be postponed to tomorrow, thereby skipping execution for one day.

There are ways to fix this race condition: for instance I could perform the check every 12 hours, and instead of scheduling the task right away, sending it to an actor that will not accept more than one task at a time.

But probably, this already exist in Akka or some extension.

Comment: You may want to use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: Well, actually I don't. :-) Everything already runs with Akka, and it seems a pretty basic thing to do with it. At worst, I will write the solution I have outlined. It not that complex, but I thought there should be a ready-made solution

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how you'd like it to work? eg, what is the internal task, the external task, what exactly do you want it to do if it misses its time, etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe the question is poorly worded. `External` and `internal` refer to the snippet above, where I make an example of a hypothetic implementation of waht I need. In other words, `external` refers to the closure which is argument to `schedule`, while `internal` to the closure which is argument to `scheduleOnce`. As for the issue of the task missing its time: it should not happen. That is the whole point of the question. The toy implementation that I sketch can miss one day under some race conditions. Hence, a more careful implementation is needed. I know how to do this properly, I am...

Comment: ...just asking whether I am wasting my time because there is some ready-made function to schedule stuff at a given time of the day in Akka.

Comment: I have reworded the question - I hope it is more clear now. The description of how I would go about doing it on my own is parenthetical, and it is there just to avoid answers like "just do it yourself - it is trivial to compute the time and reschedule".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write once, run everyday

```
val GatherStatisticsPeriod = 24 hours

private[this] val scheduled = new AtomicBoolean(false)

def calcBeforeMidnight: Duration = { 
  // TODO implement 
} 

def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) {
  self ! GatherStatisticsScheduled(scheduled.get)
  super.preRestart(reason, message)
}

def schedule(period: Duration, who: ActorRef) = 
  ServerRoot.actorSystem.scheduler
    .scheduleOnce(period)(who ! GatherStatisticsTick)

def receive = {

  case StartServer(nodeName) => 
    sender ! ServerStarted(nodeName)
    if (scheduled.compareAndSet(false, true)) 
      schedule(calcBeforeMidnight, self)

  case GatherStatisticsTick =>
    stats.update
    scheduled.set(true)
    schedule(GatherStatisticsPeriod, self) 

  case GatherStatisticsScheduled(isScheduled) =>
    if (isScheduled && scheduled.compareAndSet(false, isScheduled))
      schedule(calcBeforeMidnight, self)

}
```

I believe that Akka's scheduler handles restarts internally, one way or another. I used non-persistent way of sending a message to self - actually no strict guarantee of delivery. Also, ticks may vary, so GatherStatisticsPeriod might be a function.

Answer (score 6):

To use this kind of scheduling in Akka, you would have to roll your own or maybe use Quartz, either through [Akka Camel](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC3/scala/camel.html) or this [prototype quartz for akka](https://github.com/theatrus/akka-quartz).

If you don't need anything fancy and extremely accurate, then I would just calculate the delay to the desired first time and use that as the start delay to the schedule call, and trust the interval.

Comment: I thought of just doing this, but will the scheduler be accurate over a possibly long period, with 24 hours intervals?

Comment: Yes, the scheduler will be accurate over a long period. Just as accurate as System.nanoTime and the configuration of the scheduler tick `akka.scheduler.tick-duration` in your akka configuration.

Comment: Thank you; for now I have done this. Should I find problems I will use the solution by idonnie.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to run your task every day at 13 pm.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.time.LocalTime

val interval = 24.hours
val delay = {
  val time = LocalTime.of(13, 0).toSecondOfDay
  val now = LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay
  val fullDay = 60 * 60 * 24
  val difference = time - now
  if (difference < 0) {
    fullDay + difference
  } else {
    time - now
  }
}.seconds

system.scheduler.schedule(delay, interval)(doSomething())
```

Also remember that server timezone may be different from yours.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another way to achieve it, this can be done using [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/index.html) by [ticking](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/tick.html#source-tick) a message and filtering on time.

```
Source
  .tick(0.seconds, 2.seconds, "hello") // emits "hello" every two seconds
  .filter(_ => {
    val now = LocalDateTime.now.getSecond
    now > 20 && now < 30 // will let through only if the timing is right.
  })
  .runForeach(n => println("final sink received " + n))
```